# How to stop nodejs ajax request code after sending response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, monk

I am implementing a simple user signup form in Nodejs. I am using Express framework, Mongodb and Monk. I had implemented normal database insertion successfully. but now, when i added code to first check whether the entered email or username exists, it's gone haywire. The problem is that when an entry with same email or username is found I use `res.end` to send the error response, but the code doesn't stop there and keeps on executing other conditions and ends up inserting the document regardless of the condition and sometimes giving error that `can't set headers after they are sent`. Below is my code for ajaxsignup route

```
router.post('/ajaxsignup', function(req, res){
var db = req.db;
var formdata = req.body;

var collection = db.get('userscollection');

res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

var emailExists = collection.findOne({"email": formdata.email}, function(err, doc){
    if(err)
    {
        response = {'status': 0, 'err_code': err.code, 'err_msg': err.err};
        res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
    else
    {
        if(doc)
        {
            response = {'status': 0, 'err_code': 0, 'err_msg': 'This email id is already registered. Please use a different one.'};             
            res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    }
});//emailExists

var usernameExists = collection.findOne({"username": formdata.username}, function(err, doc){
    if(err)
    {
        response = {'status': 0, 'err_code': err.code, 'err_msg': err.err};
        res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
    else
    {
        if(doc)
        {
            response = {'status': 0, 'err_code': 0, 'err_msg': 'This username is already in use. Please use a different one.'};             
            res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    }
});//usernameExists



formdata.created = new Date();
formdata.last_updated = formdata.created;

collection.insert( formdata, function(err, doc){
    if(err)
    {
        response = {'status': 0, 'err_code': err.code, 'err_msg': err.err};
    }
    else
    {
        response = {'status': 1, 'msg': 'Thank you. You can proceed to login now.'};
    }

    res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
});//insert
});//ajaxsignup
```

Answer (score 0):

can't set headers after they are sent this error is because you write res.end three time 
there are several ways to do this

1)make mongo email and username unique and when you try to insert email or username which already exists it returns error

```
new Schema{
    email:{type:String,index: { unique: true },required:true}
    username:{type:String,index: { unique: true },required:true}
}






collection.insert(formdata,function(err,data){
       if(err){
         res.json({success:false,text:"User with this email or username already   exists!"}); 
       }
       else{
         res.json({success:true,text:"Your registration was successfull"}); 
       }
    })
```

2) second is your way

```
var emailExists=false,usernameExists=false;
collection.findOne({"$or":[{"email": formdata.email},{"username":formdata.username}], function(err, doc){
    if(err)
    {
        response = {'status': 0, 'err_code': err.code, 'err_msg': err.err};
        res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
    else
    {
        if(!doc)
        {
         collection.insert( formdata, function(err, doc){
    if(err)
    {
        response = {'status': 0, 'err_code': err.code, 'err_msg': err.err};
    }
    else
    {
        response = {'status': 1, 'msg': 'Thank you. You can proceed to login now.'};
    }

    res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
});//insert
});  
        }else{
           response = {'status': 0, 'err_code': 0, 'err_msg': 'This email id is already registered. Please use a different one.'};             
            res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    }
});
```